# In what ways are Google / Apple / FB beholden to US data collection laws

Tags: communications-law

IANAL: Said American triumvirate collects significant user-data including communications as well as temporal geo-location: a jackpot for any agency (including non state actors).

What statutes (or any other authority) compel US companies to share user-data with US Agencies (with or without a court order)?

Comment: Are you only interested in statutory authority, and do you mean "without court order"? I

Comment: @user6726. Question updated to address your inquiry